# Apple Magic mouse often loses connection

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have mac mini late 2011, up to date mac OS X and fully charged batteries. It still loses connection about 10 times per hour. It's really annoying

I've tried to remove Bluetooth.plist file, but it didn't help.

Is it solvable issue?

I use Wi Fi, and bluetooth apple keyboard.

Comment: Putting my mini up on a 1" platform above the table solved *most* of the problem for me. Mouse still goes out sometimes when (metal) keyboard gets too close to the left side of the mini. Likely its an antenna problem, as this sort of "aluminum foil on the rabbit ears" approach *works*.

Comment: Two of my colleagues have this problem, but only at the office. At home, no problem at all. They still don't know what's causing it: WiFi or bluetooth or something else. Both use the Magic Mouse with recent MacBooks.

Comment: I used to have the issue with the batteries loosing connection. Now it's the bluetooth. My new Macbook relies heavily on bluetooth (only usbc) but my headphones are interrupted and my mouse connection is intermitted as well. It's really frustrating!

Answer (score 28):

The thing is, you can fix your mouse with just your fingers. **Simply remove the back cover and bend it so that ends curve up on the Apple logo side**. Then, replace the cover. This is why buying a new mouse can fix the issue: Over time, the back cover starts to bend so that there is more room between it and the batteries.

Comment: This worked for me as the cardboard answer stopped the batteries making the circuit.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. This has changed my life. My Magic Mouse was so temperamental that if I even slightly jogged it it would disconnect. I thought it was my rechargeable AAs not holding charge, so I have been swapping out batteries to try and find out which ones were bad. I've just read your answer, bent my batter cover inwards, and it's perfect now. Thank you!

Comment: I can't believe this actually worked! been struggling with this for years and thought only one type of battery worked... Why didn't I find this 4 years ago is beyond me!

Answer (score 4):

More people have this annoyance. For me the solution was to use slightly fatter/bigger batteries (Duracell for example), or a piece of paper. When I very gently slammed my mouse on the table from a small height, the connection would drop. Probably due to a short disconnection/movement of the batteries.

Comment: I've used piece of paper, but it changed anything significantly. This is very sad.

Comment: It helps to swab the mouse contacts with a wet Q-Tip once in a while. Also periodically dampen battery ends and rub dry with cloth. It doesn't take much dirt at all to interrupt a 3 volt connection.

Answer (score 2):

The paper shim trick didn't work for me - it made the cover bulge enough to rub on the table top.  The cover bending suggestion sound risky.  So I combined the two as follows: Start with an 8 cm square of paper.  Fold it in half three times, giving a 4 cm by 2 cm pad with 8 thicknesses of paper.  Remove the cover and position it on top of the paper pad, centered, so it overhangs the pad by 2 cm on each end.  Push down on the two ends until they touch the table.  Replace the cover (without any paper shim) and test.  If necessary, repeat with a pad that has 10 or 12 layers of paper.